# Saving Time To a varchar Field

Tags: c#, winforms

Iam Working On a  WinForm..
In One oF my forms I need to save the current Time..The Corresponding Table For Saving The same Is Declared as varchar(15)..I used a datetime Picker to do the same..

How can i do this

Comment: Is it Winforms or ASP.NET? Please change your tag.

Comment: @Icarus DateTimePicker is also a control in winforms framework apart from jquery UI

Comment: The real answer is "don't".  The time should be stored as a date/time data type.  If you can change the database but you don't, you'll almost certainly regret it later.

Comment: @Devjosh Yes, but I am just referring to the fact that the question should be appropriately tagged even if the answer applies to both.

Comment: I think its better to store the SelectedValue `TimeOfDay.Ticks`, but do you really wanna store it as varchar ?

Comment: Ya i dont really wanna store it as varchar..The matter is Db designing is not done by me...So that i cant chng the datatype

Answer (score 3):

You read the Date from the dateTimePricker and do something like:

```
string theDateIWantToSaveAsString = dateTimePicker.SelectedDate.ToString();
```

Now save it to the database.

**EDIT**

To only grab the time as String...

```
string theTimeIWantToSaveInTheDatabase =  Convert.ToDateTime(dtpStartTime.Text).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Now save `theTimeIWantToSaveInTheDatabase` if that's what you want but I strongly suggest that if you have control over the database, you change the data type in your table to something suitable to store times.

Comment: thermicLogsheetInfo.log_Time = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpStartTime.Text);  Wat is getting saved is the date with time...but i juzz need to save only the time

Comment: Juzz modify the above line of code...so that only the time gets saved

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the current time from the .ToString() method of the Date class:

```
string formattedTime = Date.Now().ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

This will give you the current time in 24 hours format.
See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) page for more information on formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

If you want to save Date & Time:

```
string DateTimeToBeSaved = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
       new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

You should expand size of this column to varchar2(18);

If you wan to save only Date:

```
string DateToBeSaved = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy",
       new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

HTH.